# Should moderators (and high-rep users) give users a chance to self-edit their posts?

Tags: discussion

There have been several instances where I've posted an answer to StackExchange, and after re-reading it and doing further research I've been in the process of re-editing the post, only to find that the post has already been edited by another user within the first 30 - 60 minutes of posting it, then I have to read and understand his edits to figure out how to merge in my own.

Should mods and other high-rep users with the power to edit exercise restraint and withhold applying their "touch" to new posts until the original poster has had an opportunity to read and rework his post?

Not everyone can post a perfect answer immediately and it's frustrating to find that the edit you were about to make is complicated by the need to read through another user's edits.

I'll add that I've only run into this on skeptics.stackexchange.com, none of the other SE sites I frequent seem to have mods that are so quick to edit.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: If you mind this you should reread before posting ;) but it's true that moderation on this subsite is very different from the rest of the network.

Comment: 30-60 minutes? Do you mean seconds?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I shouldn't answer this question, because it is directed at my behaviour, but:

Trivia question: As of today, what percentage of Skeptics.SE questions received their first answer within the first 60 minutes after creation (excluding self-answered questions, because they are often pre-prepared)?

Take a guess and then hover over the grey box to find the answer.

> 854 of 6216 questions = 13.7%

It was a quick and dirty query, so it may be wrong, but as some weak evidence of that figure, here are the fastest guns in the Skeptics West:

- [Do any Jewish organizations lobby for destruction of Israel?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3368)
- [Did Soviet miners drill a hole to Hell?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19748)
- [Were there any Jews among the Nazi top people?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3364)
- [Is "Man vs. Wild" staged?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4521)
- [When will humans become immune to antibiotics?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23896)

I think it is unreasonable to ask that a question not be edited for a period when it is open to answering, and is perhaps quite likely to garner an answer, so I think we need to take a different approach to solving the problem of people still editing.

Suggestions include:

- Editing it off-line in a text editor. I often do this.
- Editing it off-line in a Markdown-aware editor. [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io) is an example (although I have no reason to endorse it.)
- Create a question and immediately delete it. You can edit it in the deleted state, and undelete it when you are ready. (Mods and users with 10K rep could also edit it, but they are unlikely to be inclined to do so.
- Conflict detection: If two conflicting edits are made simultaneously, Stack Exchange will discard one - but tries to keep the more substantial edit.

Final note: The question talks about "moderators and high-rep users". Over 100 users have sufficient rep to edit, but it also applies to suggested edits from low-rep users.

Comment: At least some of the "fastest in the west" turn out to be sockpuppets :-(